# Search for records where two fields match

Tags: java, lucene

I have an index which includes these fields ( post.id, topic.id, contents).

I want to search for records where "post.id = topic.id".

I tried

```
+(post.id:topic.id)
```

but I had no luck.

I'm fairly new to Lucene.

My generated query looks like this.

```
+(forum.id:9)  +(contents:test*)  +(post.id:topic.id)
```

I think it should fetch me any record that contains test* in contents and where post.id is the same as topic.id but it's not working as I expected.

I may be getting this all wrong.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any method that can do that directly. But a workaround is to use the Lucene join feature (either index or query time joins). Please have a look [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/join/org/apache/lucene/search/join/package-summary.html) to know how to use it.

In Solr, you can do something like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1/select/?q={!join from=post.id to=topic.id} content:test
```